# css select svg use xlink

Tags: css, svg

This is inline svg in html:

```
    <svg id="svg1"><use xlink:href = "#mysvgsymbol"/></<svg>
    <svg id="svg2"><use xlink:href = "#mysvgsymbol"/></<svg>
    <svg id="svg3"><use xlink:href = "#mysvgsymbol"/></<svg>

    #mysvgsymbol
```

is in another svg and has several layers g each with an own id.

how to select the layers g in relation to the svg ids, so that I can style the same layers differently in each svg use link?

Is it at all possible to select across a use tag into the href svg?

Comment: Please try to clarify your issue. I'm having a hard time understanding

Comment: `<use>` is a view of the underlying content. You can't really display it differently.

Comment: As an example: <svg id="svg1" style="fill:red">. This will allso effect layers in the symbol. I just wonder, if I can select layers in the referenced symbol directly. But it seem to be like Robert said. It is not possible.